# Minimum sample size in nonparametric data

Tags: nonparametric, sample

My population has more or less 80,000 individuals and I would like to take a small sample with a high probability it is really close to the whole population. The problem is that my data is nonparametric (variable's probability distributions do not follow a typical distribution such as normal).

Comment: What do you mean by "nonparametric"? What do you mean by "the same"?

Comment: By "the same" I mean as similar as possible and by "nonparametric" I edited the question :)

Comment: You will need to characterize "really close" in a quantitative way in order for people to provide useful answers. As an example, you might ask how to take a sample whose mean will have a $95\%$ chance of lying within a value $\epsilon$ of the population mean, given that you assume the population mean is $\mu$.

Comment: I cannot define it because I do not know if I have to check the mean or something else... I do not know what I need.